# how does pof generate cities from countries chosen manually or automatic

Tags: mobile, web

How does the site pof.com generate the cities based on the country you choose?

when you click the country you currently live in, in the city selection there is a drop down menu of different cities. How did they accomplish this?

i would like to know this to help guide registration in my website based on city of residence.

were all the cities from each individual country entered manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/?hl=pt-br) for that.